# How to Reorder tableview row in a tableview controller to a specified index row without dragging and dropping?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, tableview

I'm looking for a way on how to reorder a tableview row to the 0th index position based a bool value I get from another view controller? Stuck on this for a while. Only found answers on how to drag and reorder. I want to reorder cells without dragging and dropping.

Comment: Just relocate your records in data source container and call `tableView.reloadData()`

Comment: Thanks @Asperi Will you be able to provide an example please? And where should I call this? I'm using custom cells and dequeueReusableCell in tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell function

Comment: Comments are not for code - provide you controller code in question and I'll see.